# how to stop label to float on top on focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, material-design

how to stop label to float on top on focus on date picker using Material ui ?

I tried lot of method nothing works.I used this `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}` but not work
here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-joji-32rtwq?file=/demo.tsx:435-440

```
export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker label="dd" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`InputLabelProps`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#shrink) for the [`TextField`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) in the [MUI DatePicker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-picker/) can be passed via the `textField` slot in the component's [`slotProps`](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/custom-components/#overriding-components). For example:

```
<DatePicker
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      InputLabelProps: {
        shrink: true
      }
    }
  }}
  label="dd"
/>
```

Working CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-datepicker-label-shrink-vhs8wf?file=/demo.tsx